# String comparison throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, compare

I am trying to find a user in my database, searching for email and phonenumber.
How ever, if I use a List or IEnumerable I'm getting a null refence exception. If I don't use any of those, an "Not supported by SQL ... " is thrown.

My method:

```
public List<tblMember> getAllMembers()
{
    return db.tblMembers.ToList();
}

private void confirmMembership(string email, int phoneNumber)
{
    //var allMembers = db.tblMembers.AsEnumerable(); throws same exception
    tblMember member = getAllMembers().FirstOrDefault(x => x.email.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.phoneNumber == phoneNumber); //This line throws exception, around email.Equals()
    if (member != null)
    {
        member.isConfirmed = true;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else
        throw new Exception("Member not found");
}
```

If I perform the search like this, no exception is thrown:

```
private void confirmMembership(string email, int phoneNumber)
{
    //var allMembers = db.tblMembers.AsEnumerable(); throws same exception
    tblMember member = getAllMembers().FirstOrDefault(x => x.email == email && x.phoneNumber == phoneNumber);
    if (member != null)
    {
        member.isConfirmed = true;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else
        throw new Exception("Member not found");
}
```

How can this be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case you are calling Equals() on an object that is null.

```
x.email.Equals(...)
```

This throws an exception.

In the second case you are comparing two things one of which might be null

```
x.email == email
```

---

Here is the most current based on comments:

```
private void confirmMembership(string email, int phoneNumber)
{
    tblMember member = tblMembers.FirstOrDefault((x) => {
        if (x.email == null)  return false;
        return SqlMethods.Like(x.email,email) && x.phoneNumber == phoneNumber); 
      }
    if (member != null)
    {
        member.isConfirmed = true;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else
        throw new Exception("Member not found");
}
```

---

Here is another way that won't throw an exception:

```
private void confirmMembership(string email, int phoneNumber)
{
    //var allMembers = db.tblMembers.AsEnumerable(); throws same exception
    tblMember member = getAllMembers().FirstOrDefault((x) => {
        if (x.email == null)  return false;
        return x.email.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.phoneNumber == phoneNumber); 
      }
    if (member != null)
    {
        member.isConfirmed = true;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else
        throw new Exception("Member not found");
}
```

Comment: So if email is null just for one row it will throw exception?

Comment: As noted in my answer, statement lambdas as shown here can't be converted into expression trees.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have only added x.email != null to my code, since the parameter email will never be null.

Comment: @KLIM8D: Right, that's what I'd hope. I'd not noticed that you're already calling `ToList` before this, so the problem of the expression tree conversion is irrelevant, although I'd still use the compound form as per my answer.

Comment: @KLIM8D: Please re-read my now edited answer; I hadn't spotted that you were querying a `List<T>` before. I would strongly urge you to move the filtering into the database - fetching the whole table each time you want to find one member will perform *horribly* as soon as you have a lot of members.

Comment: @KLIM8D - I changed this code to not support the parameter being null.

Comment: @KLIM8D - seem my edit, I fixed the issue with `OrdinalIgnoreCase` by useing `SqlMethods.Like()`

Comment: @Hogan Does `SqlMethods.Like()` ignore case etc. like `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` ?

Comment: @KLIM8D - Yes, the like operator in SQL ignores case, that is why I used it.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks, I seems to work very well with `SqlMethods.Like()`

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because `x.email` is null. If it is null, calling a member of it throws an exception.

```
x.email.Equals(...)   ==> exception
```

However, you are allowed to compare two values that may be null

```
x.email == email      ==> OK.
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's because `x.email` is null for some value of x.

Try:

```
tblMember member = db.tblMembers
     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.email != null
                     && x.email.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                     && x.phoneNumber == phoneNumber);
```

EDIT: I've only just noticed that `getAllMembers()` returns a `List<T>` so you don't have to worry about the expression tree conversion I was talking about before - but your current code is fetching *all* the data from the database each time you call this method. Do you *really* want that? The code I've provided above will do the filtering *in the database* which is surely what you'd be interested in.

Comment: I think this will fail if the parameter email is passed in as null.  In that case you expect it to only match on phonenumber.

Comment: @Hogan: I'd actually expect it to fail for all values in that case. It's not clear whether the OP would want to match the first value where there's a null email address in the table. (I'd expect the parameter to be non-nullable really, which should be validated at the start of the method.)

Comment: Sure, except the example he gives that does not use OrdinalIgnoreCase would perform as I described.  I guess I take requirements at face value.

Comment: @Hogan: Actually I'm not sure it *would* behave like that. It depends on the SQL translation used, but I've seen LINQ scenarios where you've had to explicitly say `(x.email == null && email == null) || x.email == email` in order to match NULL==NULL.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've without getAllMembers() and performing the filtering in the database. How ever this throws "No supported translation to SQL" exception. Atleast when I try it in LinQPad.
"Method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL."

Comment: @KLIM8D: Okay, so you need to tell us whether you're using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework, and we can try to help you further. Pulling the whole table into memory on each call is really not a good long-term solution.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using LINQ to SQL. It would be great if we could do the filtering in the database instead

Comment: @KLIM8D: You should be able to; there's a table of supported calls somewhere. I won't be able to look for several hours, but I'll try to check it tonight.

Comment: @KLIM8D - The most current version of my answer uses `SqlMethods.Like()` to run the query on the server side without case issues, as Jon suggests.  No need to look it up Jon.